# do_install() in my recipe, is not get called

Tags: bitbake

Below is the recipe which is very identical to the one I am working on. 
I do 'bitbake -v -c compile hostapd' to compile. Bitbake works fine upto do_compile(), but the compilation is terminated with that and do_install() is not get called. So, not able to install the binaries.
NOTE: If I include 'install' in do_compile(), it is able to install files.
Help me in this regard.

```
DESCRIPTION = "hostapd"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM ="file://CONTRIBUTIONS;md5=443127d1b581020d711c3bbbf3656d69"

DEPENDS = "libnl openssl"
inherit module

FILESPATH =+ "${TOPDIR}/../wifi/:"
SRC_URI = "file://hostap \
"

S = "${WORKDIR}/hostap"

do_configure() {     
    true
    echo "****************do_confige***************"
}

do_compile() {
    true
    echo "************do_compile****************"
}

do_install() {
    true
    echo "*************do_install**************"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you call `bitbake <recipe> -c compile`,  it'll only run the compile task. Just call `bitbake. <recipe>` to have it run through all tasks including installation and packaging.

Comment: Yeah, when execute 'bitbake -v <recipe.bb>', do_install get called.:)

Comment: Also to add: To execute only do_install() in recipe, specify the task 'install' in the command 'bitbake -c install <recipe_name>'. Same is for other tasks too.

Comment: Sure. And you can also use `-C <task>`,  that'll run the requested task and all tasks after that one.